# Access to the Environment.SpecialFolder

Tags: java, file-io

My Desktop Application needs to store and retrieve data from files stored in ProgramData folder (in Win 7). How can I get access to the Environment.SpecialFolder regardless of the Operating System whether it is Win 7 or Win XP? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure Java provides this. You can access it, on Windows 7 through the environment variable `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` or `ProgramData`:

```
File appData = new File(System.getenv("CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA"));
```

Comment: Does this apply to Win XP too?

Comment: It appears that on Windows 7 you can access it through %ProgramData% as well. On Windows XP, I don't recall seeing this folder. Could it be, on Windows XP, that you're looking for `%APPDATA%`?